# This function has a return type of 'int', but doesn't end with a return statement flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in my function there is a warning about the return (This function has a return type of 'int', but doesn't end with a return statement. ) but I dont know what is the problem . any idea?

```
int checkValueIndex() {
   if (selectedValue != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < mList.length; i++) {
        if (mList[i].name == selectedValue.name) {
          return i;
            }
          }
        } else {
          return null;
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function return null value ,add (?) so it will accept null  as follow:

```
 int? checkValueIndex() {
   if (selectedValue != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < mList.length; i++) {
        if (mList[i].name == selectedValue.name) {
          return i;
            }
          }
        } else {
          return null;
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Error says you have to return some `int` value. Add `?` in return type so that you can allow return `null` value as well.

try this code:

```
int? checkValueIndex() {
  if (selectedValue != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mList.length; i++) {
      if (mList[i].name == selectedValue.name) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```